# Scala Play connecting to MySql shows runtime error "Table 'token' doesn't exist"

Tags: mysql, scala, jdbc, playframework

I am attempting to read and write from a remote MySQL database from a Play for Scala controller using jdbc, and SBT is displaying at runtime the error:

> "Table '{dbname}.token' doesn't exist"

Sql calls (selects) complete as expected despite this error.

**My questions are:**

1. What is this 'token' table and why would I want it?
2. Is there a way to turn off the requirement for the 'token' table

I have googled this aggressively and not found an answer, or indeed anything about this token table.

**the details are as follows:**

**versions:**

- scala 2.11.6
- play 2.2.6

**relevant configurations in application.conf:**

```
evolutionplugin=disabled
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://152.135.194.149/mydb"
db.default.user=someuser
db.default.password="somepassword"
```

**relevant parts of the controller:**

```
import play.api.db._
import play.api.Play.current
def test = Action {

  DB.withConnection { conn =>
    val stm = conn.createStatement()
    val res = stm.executeQuery("""
    SELECT  *
    FROM    sometable
    """.stripMargin)

    while (res.next()) {
      // this println succeeds in showing the selected data
      println(res.getString(1), res.getString(2), res.getString(3), res.getString(4))
    }

  }

  Status(200)("good enough")
} // test
```

**complete error message from SBT:**

```
[ERROR] [11/15/2017 16:31:43.041] [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [TaskInvocation] Table 'mydb.token' doesn't exist
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'mydb.token' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2825)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2459)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2376)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2360)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.PreparedStatementHandle.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementHandle.java:205)
    at anorm.Sql$class.executeUpdate(Anorm.scala:473)
    at anorm.SqlQuery.executeUpdate(Anorm.scala:481)
    at service.PgSqlUserService$$anonfun$deleteExpiredTokens$1.apply(PgSqlUserService.scala:521)
    at service.PgSqlUserService$$anonfun$deleteExpiredTokens$1.apply(PgSqlUserService.scala:512)
    at play.api.db.DBApi$class.withConnection(DB.scala:82)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPApi.withConnection(DB.scala:276)
    at play.api.db.DB$$anonfun$withConnection$3.apply(DB.scala:162)
    at play.api.db.DB$$anonfun$withConnection$3.apply(DB.scala:162)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.api.db.DB$.withConnection(DB.scala:162)
    at service.PgSqlUserService.deleteExpiredTokens(PgSqlUserService.scala:512)
    at securesocial.core.UserServicePlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply$mcV$sp(UserService.scala:137)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$9.run(Scheduler.scala:80)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$3$$anon$2.run(Scheduler.scala:241)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

[error] a.d.TaskInvocation - Table 'mydb.token' doesn't exist
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'mydb.token' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
```

**The permissions of the MySQL user:**

```
mysql> select Host, User, Select_priv, Insert_priv, Update_priv, Delete_priv, Create_priv, Drop_priv, Alter_priv, Super_priv, Create_tmp_table_priv, Create_tablespace_priv from user where Host="%" and User="someuser";
+------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| Host | User       | Select_priv | Insert_priv | Update_priv | Delete_priv | Create_priv | Drop_priv | Alter_priv | Super_priv | Create_tmp_table_priv | Create_tablespace_priv |
+------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| %    | someuser   | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y         | Y          | Y          | Y                     | Y                      |
+------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Notes:**

- I am additionally using Securesocial, which utilizes Postgres.
- I intend in the future to enable evolution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Play 2.2 is quite deprecated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue turns out to be related to securesocial competing for the db.default configuration.

since this project is deployed on heroku, the db.* configurations were set in the Procfile, rather than application.conf, and were set to use postgres on a different server.

redeclaring db.default in application.conf cause securesocial to attempt to query the mysql database and, thus, the 'table token doesn't exist' error.

the solution was to provide db configuration other than default and use that:

application.conf: use 'custom' (or any other string) instead of 'default'

```
db.custom.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.custom.url="jdbc:mysql://152.135.194.149/mydb"
db.custom.user=someuser
db.custom.password="somepassword"
```

controller: call withConnection() with config from above

```
import play.api.db._
import play.api.Play.current
def test = Action {

  // note the 'custom'
  DB.withConnection("custom") { conn =>
    val stm = conn.createStatement()
    val res = stm.executeQuery("""
    SELECT  *
    FROM    sometable
    """.stripMargin)

    while (res.next()) {
      // this println succeeds in showing the selected data
      println(res.getString(1), res.getString(2), res.getString(3), res.getString(4))
    }

  }

  Status(200)("good enough")
} // test
```